# Function calling from custom OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, function, onclicklistener

I've **Main_Activity.class** file. There I am defining a custom function **myFunction()** . In this function I want to call an externally defined custom **OnClickListener** which will call the function recursively.

In **Main_Activity** the button is  defined as

```
private Button button;
.
.
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
.
.
```

My **myFunction()** is defined inside **Main_Activity.class**. And inside this function the **OnClickListener** for button is defined. From this **OnClickListener**, I can easily call the **myFunction()**.

```
private void myFunction(){
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                 myFunction();
            }
        });
}
```

But I want to define a custom MyClickListenerClass for button and call the myFunction() from that external class.

How can it be possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

Activity:

```
 public class Main_Activity extends Activity
{

    Button button;
    MainActivity act;
    MyClickListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            listener = new MyClickListener(this);
            myFunction();
        }

    public void myFunction()
        {
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);
            Log.i("Fun clicked from", "sdfnd");
        }
}
```

and class:

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener 
{
    MainActivity act;
      public MyClickListener(MainActivity act) { 
         this.act=act;

      }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            act.myFunction();

        } 
}
```

Comment: Is there any another way around to do that ?